# Is it possible to use "Tracking Protection" APIs to block new URLs

Tags: firefox-addon

I was wondering if it is possible to add a new rule to the "Tracking Protection" to block a set of new URLs. Seems like currently it is only possible to change the updating URL,  browser.safebrowsing.provider.mozilla.updateURL. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to append new rules to the current list.

Answer (score 0):

Safebrowsing is not the same as tracking protection.

And if you wish to block certain domains there are plenty of addons that provide content blocking functionality. Those addons obviously use [common underlying mechanism](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/WebRequest.jsm) that could also be used by your addon.

Comment: Currently "Tracking Protection" is only enabled in the Safe Browning. That's the reason why the pref has the "safebrowsing" keyword.

Comment: Note that using `webRequest` and adding filters into it slow downs the browser. Also loading blocking list usually consume too much RAM. It seems that the "Tracking Protection" mechanism is much more optimized and hence it is not affecting browser performance a lot. That's the main reason I am interested in the “Tracking Protection” APIs.